# LIstBoxFor Not Validating Properly MVC

Tags: jquery, validation, model-view-controller

I am attempting to use validation on a page using an HTML.ListboxFor() control.  I have several HTML.DropDownListFor() controls on my page that validate as designed however, any time that I select an item in the List Box, the page fires the HttpPost Action Method on the controller, bypassing the form.submit() function which would fire my validation.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed to solve this issue.

My HTML is as follows...

```
    //....more HTML

        <div class="span6">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RaceAsList)
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.RaceAsList, Race.SelectRace, Html.GetI18LHtmlAttributesFor(m => m.Race, new {  @class = "span4 subtext upper defaultIsZero hasPatientDeclines", tabindex = 13 }))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RaceAsList)
                            <br />
                            <span class="muted">@(Html.Raw(Kiosk.ResourceFiles.Resource.RaceHelp))</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Ethnicities)
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ethnicities, Ethnicities.SelectEthnicities, Html.GetI18LHtmlAttributesFor(m => m.Ethnicities, new { @class = "span4 upper defaultIsZero hasPatientDeclines", tabindex = 14 }))
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Ethnicities)
                        </div>
                    </div>

//....more HTML
```

My .js is as follows:

```
//...more javascript

$("form").submit(function() {
            if (preSubmit != undefined && $.isFunction(preSubmit)) {
                preSubmit();
            }
            if (!isForeignAddress) {
                $(".phone").each(function() {
                    nums = pv.stripAlphaChars($(this).val());
                    $(this).val(nums);
                });
            }
            if ($(".requireOptOut").size() > 0) {
                requireOptOut($(".requireOptOut:first"));
            }

            return true;
        });

//...more javascript
```

My controller is as follows:

```
//...more C#

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult PatientInfo(KioskPatientEntity model, FormCollection form)
        {
            LoadFromSession();
            var kioskPatient = PatientManagerService.GetPatientBySession(NavigationSession.SessionPk, Environment, KioskPatientChildPrefetch.None);

            if (kioskPatient != null)
            {
                kioskPatient.MergeChanges(model);
            }
            else
            {
                kioskPatient = model;
                kioskPatient.SessionPk = NavigationSession.SessionPk;
            }

            var properties = new []
                    {
                        KioskPatientFieldIndex.FirstName.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.MiddleName.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.LastName.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Gender.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Ssn.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.SsnOptedOut.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.BirthDate.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Address1.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Address2.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Zip.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.City.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.State.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Country.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Race.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Ethnicities.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.PreferredLanguage.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.HearFrom.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.Practice.ToString()
                        ,KioskPatientFieldIndex.AlternateLocation.ToString()

                    };

            kioskPatient.InitializeRaceList(ListManagerService.GetRaceList());
            //var List = kioskPatient.RaceAsList;
            //var raceComingtrhough = kioskPatient.Race;
            //var nameComing = kioskPatient.FirstName;
            return SaveKioskPatientEntity(kioskPatient, properties,
                                   new SequenceButtonTypes[] {SequenceButtonTypes.NextButton});

        }

//...more C#
```

Comment: By default, simply selecting an item from a list box will not fire off a POST submit. You **must** have some other javascript running that is performing a submit on change. Also, the JS you posted wouldn't stop a form submit even if things were invalid, you never `return false` or have an `e.preventDefault()` in there

Comment: I applogize, there is a button that triggers the form submit.  If there is no selection of the List Box, the entire page validation works as as the form is submitted upon the button click.  If there is a selection in the List Box, the form.submit() function is not fired, rather, the HttpPost PatientInfo() is fired.

Comment: I see.. in that case, something must be erroring out in your Javascript. Open your browser console and check for any errors on submit

Comment: I have done this and there are no js errors.  The form.submit() is never hit, rather, the HttpPost PatientInfo() is fired but only if there is a selection within the List Box.  I have changed the control to an HTML.DropDownListFor() control for troubleshooting, and the page functioned as designed, just not with the List Box.

Comment: Are you sure the `form.submt()` function isn't being called? Your current javascript `form.submt()` listener will not stop a form submission as you don't have any `return false;` in there. Try adding a `console.log('hello');` to your `form.submit()` to make sure that it is firing

Comment: Upon the button click, the function is firing when the List Box does not have a selection.  It is not being called if there is a selection within the ListBox.

Comment: I'm sorry and I'm not trying to be rude here, but have you even tried what I suggested? Without seeing **all** of your javascript, and the html, I'm am simply throwing out basic debugging steps that you *should* know how to do. From what you have posted...there is nothing that could prevent your method being called when something has been selected vs not selected

Comment: I have put breakpoints on the form.submit() as well as the Controller ActionMethod.  I am aware that the information given is limited, and I wanted to make sure that it was not something this simple.  I have done the simple debugging and, I agree with you, that there should be nothing that is causing this to happen, however, it is still working as I have explained.  I thank you for your efforts.